# how to download file on server which don't have direct links in asp.net 4.0 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**asp.net 4.0**

I have googled for nearly a week now about this thing but couldn't find any solution to my problem..
I want to download files to store them on my server.
I know about using a webclient it does the job but only for direct links

```
 webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile(fileUrl, filePath);
```

it doesn't work for files which don't have direct links!
how can I download these type of files?

direct link: www.example.com/pic.jpg

indirect links: www.example.com/download?xxxxxxx

the specific website on which I faced this problem is www.zbigz.com

you can get an indirect link by copying this link [torrent link](http://torcache.net/torrent/ACDD7792CDC413CC5A0398A6E0F96EDFD308F937.torrent?title=%5Bkat.ph%5D100.amazing.3d.hd.wallpapers.1366.x.768) on www.zbigz.com and it will cache the file in a minute and will provide you the link under "free" category..

I do have a link generated by this site but it won't work for you as this site don't support downloading of shared link.
http://34044.zbigz.com/core/outfile.php?did=d85ade21e892f386e55a556ce47b654b

**edit**
For all those who think this is for scraping!
I want to download those file but can't do that directly as my university has blocked many websites including this so being a cse student i thought of this another way of downloading them to my server and then to my machine from server.

```
        byte[] content;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            content = br.ReadBytes(500000);
            br.Close();
        }
        response.Close();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        try
        {
            bw.Write(content);
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
            bw.Close();
        }
```

this is the code I am trying, works for direct link but gives 403 forbidden error on the above mentioned link.

Comment: Perhaps `zbigz.com` doesn't want people to be scraping torrent links off of their site?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why don't you just use `HttpWebRequest` to do this which is what your browser uses.

Comment: I read on another question that doing this way is easiest but thanks I will try HttpWebRequest if that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `WebClient` but use `WebRequest`

WebRequest can handle redirects automatically.

See [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)
And [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)
from which WebRequest derivies

Comment: 403 means Forbidden, I can't give you access ;-)